# How to locate and click on the Accept All button using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

When I call the `<div>` tag and his class value then it does not response.

HTML:

```
<div id="ccmgt_explicit_accept" class="privacy-prompt-button primary-button ccmgt_accept_button ">
    <span>Accept All</span>
</div>
```

Snapshot of the element:

[image]

Comment: Post your code, confirm the url you are trying to access, and explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Just i am finding here xpath for selenium <div id="ccmgt_explicit_accept" class="privacy-prompt-button primary-button ccmgt_accept_button "><span>Accept All</span></div>

Comment: @user2508281 With the code that you posted in above comment, you may try `driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ccmgt_explicit_accept')`, but I don't think this would help much, for there could be some related HMTL too that may conflict with this code. Hence. more HMTL code if pasted would be better. If possible, share the website link

Comment: I'd suggest @AnandGautam's answer, but if you want to use XPath and class attribute try `//div[@class="privacy-prompt-button primary-button ccmgt_accept_button"]`.

Answer (score -1):

To click on <kbd>Accept All</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#ccmgt_explicit_accept > span"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Accept All']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hey pal.
Could you please help me with these questions? I'm kinda lost:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73903953/looping-on-selenium-java-depending-on-the-rows-thrown-by-sql-sentence-and-fill/73904563#73904563
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73903125/trying-to-pass-values-from-sql-server-table-in-sendkeys-selenium-java-avoi?noredirect=1#comment130499884_73903125

Comment: @new_programmer Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: Hey pal. You explain very well. Could you please take a look at these questions i sent you? I need to solve it :/