# Trying to pass values from SQL SERVER table in sendKeys (Selenium & JAVA) - AVOIDING HARDCODE, best way to achieve that

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I'm trying to pass a value to the **sendKeys** function from 2 different SQL SENTENCES.

I want to execute a SQL SENTENCE (SQL SERVER database), copy the value and place it inside the **sendKeys** function.

---

My CODE looks like this:

```
package first;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;

public class myCodes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Steven\\Desktop\\Folder\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://testingserver/backend");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("randomPassw0rd@");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-form\"]/fieldset/div[3]/div[2]/button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-bbb-backend-stores\"]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-bbb-backend-stores\"]/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]/div/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_filter_frontend_label\"]")).sendKeys("group");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_filter_frontend_label\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_table\"]/tbody/tr/td[1]")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".col-attr-code col-attribute_code")).click(); 
    //Thread.sleep(6000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"manage-options-panel\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/input")).sendKeys("122");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"save\"]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    
    
    }

}
```

I need to replace these lines:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_filter_frontend_label\"]")).sendKeys("group");
```

i don't want to pass "group" as a harcoded value but fetch it from this SQL sentence:

```
SELECT value
from test
where claim = 45;
```

And also:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"manage-options-panel\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/input")).sendKeys("122");
```

i don't want to pass "122" as a harcoded value but fetch it from this SQL sentence:

```
SELECT value
from test32
where claim = 34;
```

What would it be the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Refer these links:   https://hevodata.com/learn/java-connect-to-microsoft-sql-server/,   https://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/connect-to-microsoft-sql-server-via-jdbc,       https://artoftesting.com/connect-to-sql-server-java

Comment: Hey @AbiSaran could you please help me to make it work on my code? I'm kinda lost :/