# Looping on Selenium & JAVA depending on the rows thrown by SQL SENTENCE and filling in the different values obtained

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to loop depending on the number of rows thrown by a given SQL SENTENCE.

Suppose that my SQL SERVER query is:

```
select * 
from TABLE1;
```

and it throws **4 rows**, take a look at the image below:

[image]

So, i will need to loop **4 times**

This is my code:

```
package first;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;

public class myCodes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Steven\\Desktop\\Folder\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://testingserver/backend");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("randomPassw0rd@");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-form\"]/fieldset/div[3]/div[2]/button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-bbb-backend-stores\"]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-bbb-backend-stores\"]/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]/div/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_filter_frontend_label\"]")).sendKeys("group");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_filter_frontend_label\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_table\"]/tbody/tr/td[1]")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".col-attr-code col-attribute_code")).click(); 
    //Thread.sleep(6000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"manage-options-panel\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/input")).sendKeys("122");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"save\"]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    
    
    }

}
```

---

**I want to achieve this:**

Since the image shown above i will need to loop 4 times:

The **first loop** will need to fill the value from column "value2" and row 1 inside function sendKeys()

Take a look at the image:

[image]

The **second loop** will need to fill the value from column "value2" and row 2 inside function sendKeys()

Take a look at the image:

[image]

Then, The **third loop** will need to fill the value from column "value2" and row 3 inside function sendKeys()

and The **fourth loop** will need to fill the value from column "value2" and row 4 inside function sendKeys().

I've tried without success to achieve that.

What would it be the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single `for` loop if the positions of columns are known and fixed. From the provided code, I have tried to figure out the xpaths but recheck them if it's compatible.

Try the following snippet -

```
String table_header_xpath = "//*[@id='attributeGrid_table']/thead/tr";
String table_row_xpath = "//*[@id='attributeGrid_table']/tbody/tr";

// Below code is to get the indexes of columns dynamically.
// It the values are static you can just hard code the indexes below and skip the first for loop

int id_col_index = -1;
int name_col_index = -1;
int value_col_index = -1;
int value2_col_index = -1;

// Section to find the indexes - START

WebElement header_row = driver.findElement(By.xpath(table_header_xpath));
List<WebElement> header_cells = header_row.findElements(By.xpath("./child::*"));

for (WebElement header_cell : header_cells){
    if(header_cell.getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
        id_col_index = header_cells.indexOf(header_cell);
        continue;
    }
    if(header_cell.getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
        name_col_index = header_cells.indexOf(header_cell);
        continue;
    }
    if(header_cell.getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("value")){
        value_col_index = header_cells.indexOf(header_cell);
        continue;
    }
    if(header_cell.getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("value2")){
        value2_col_index = header_cells.indexOf(header_cell);
        continue;
    }
}

// Section to find the indexes - END

List<WebElement> table_body_rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(table_row_xpath));

// Iterating over rows -
for(WebElement row : table_body_rows){

    List<WebElement> cells_in_a_row = row.findElements(By.xpath("./child::*"));

    WebElement idInCurrentRow = cells_in_a_row.get(id_col_index);
    WebElement nameInCurrentRow = cells_in_a_row.get(name_col_index);
    WebElement valueInCurrentRow = cells_in_a_row.get(value_col_index);
    WebElement value2InCurrentRow = cells_in_a_row.get(value2_col_index);

    /*

    You can check for validations based on values of above elements 
    and enter new values at the same time

    */

}
```

Comment: But how do you manage the SQL PART? I need to execute the SQL SENTENCE and then, start looping

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to store the data retrieved from the database into a List variable. And then iterate through the list with a for loop. Am not sure if for the entry into the webpage is done after a refresh, full login procedure etc. This answer is based on the assumption that the xpath is not changing where the value is entered:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SqlLoopQuestion {

    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Steven\\Desktop\\Folder\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        // initiate website
        driver.get("https://testingserver/backend");

        // login to application
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).sendKeys("randomPassw0rd@");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-form\"]/fieldset/div[3]/div[2]/button")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        // go to backend stores
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-bbb-backend-stores\"]/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-bbb-backend-stores\"]/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]/div/ul/li[3]/a")).click();

        List<String> valuesToEnter = retrieveValues();

        for(String text : valuesToEnter){

            // enter data
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_filter_frontend_label\"]")).sendKeys("group");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_filter_frontend_label\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attributeGrid_table\"]/tbody/tr/td[1]")).click();

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"manage-options-panel\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/input")).sendKeys(text);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"save\"]/a")).click();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }

    }


    static List<String > retrieveValues(){

        // database variables
        Connection conn = null;
        String dbConnectionPath = "DATABASECONNECTIONPATH";
        String dbUserName       = "DATABASEUSERNAME";
        String dbPassword       = "DATABASEPASSWORD";

        // variables to execute the query
        Statement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;
        
        // list to store the values from the database
        List<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<>();

        // establish database connection
        try{

            // build the connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnectionPath, dbUserName, dbPassword);


        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Database connection error -->" + e);
        }

        try{

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("QUERY" );

            // if there is a value in the next column
            // iterate with a while loop
            while(rs.next()){

                // add all the values in the column to the list
                valuesList.add(rs.getString("value 2"));

            }

        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }

        return valuesList;
    }
}
```